# Change activit with Spinner on Android Studio with Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-spinner

Lets say i have a Spinner with two objects in it Object A and Object B.

And i have two activities named "A activity" and "B activity".

How can i change activity by selecting an item from Spinner.

I know i have to use Spinner on Item Selected Listener but can't do it on my own please help.

```
Spinner.onItemSelectedListener
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by this code if anyone interested

```
 val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.lotto_choices, R.layout.spinner_list
        ).also { adapter ->
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_list)
            spinner.adapter = adapter
        }
        spinner.setSelection(0)

val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object :
            AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                var intent: Intent
                if (position == 0) {
                    return
                }
                if (position == 1 ) {
                    intent = Intent(this@SayisalActivity, SuperActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                if (position == 2 ) {
                    intent = Intent(this@SayisalActivity, SansActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                if (position == 3 ) {
                    intent = Intent(this@SayisalActivity, OnnumaraActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                return
            }
        }
```

Comment: Changed this to this@MainActivity it now opens the app and red underline has gone but when i select the 3rd item in spinner app crashes